# Treating a complex argument as a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

I've been experimenting with putting logical arguments into matrices by considering it a system of equations and converting the arguments into boolean algebra notation.
For example letting p$\rightarrow$q =$\bar p$+q.I was wondering if this idea already has a name or is actually used. 
For example:
Given the argument with premises:
1)(-p$\lor$-q)$\rightarrow$(r$\wedge$s)
2)(r$\rightarrow$t)
3)-t
I then put the argument in the form of a matrix after simplifying and converting to a boolean algebraic expression. 
$\Bigg($ $\begin{matrix} pq&rs&0&0\\0&0&\bar r&t\\0&0&0&t \end{matrix}$ $\Bigg)$. Where 0 does not denote F, instead denotes that there is not an entry in the row. Is it then accepted to simplify arguments and determine satisfiability of system specifications using linear algebra and not just logical syllogisms and their identities? If so, is there a name for this method?

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/BOOK/partE.pdf

Comment: "complex" in the title is misleading...but I can't come up with anything better.

Comment: I can see what you mean there. I was just giving a simple example because I didn't want to spend 20 minutes trying to write a large matrix. I do also see the ambiguity with complex variables but I can't really think of a better title either.